# How to get a URL after redirect when u got any bad response code?

Tags: java, connection, urlconnection

I have a link with redirect to any website. I need to find a URL after all redirects. My code works perfect until I got any bad response, for example "HTTP response code 401".

For example we will shorten URL **https://google.com** to **https://short.url**.

```
URLConnection con = new URL("https://short.url").openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
URLAfterRedirect = String.valueOf(con.getURL());
is.close();
```

So, if the request is okay we got a URL (**https://google.com**) after the redirect. But if there is some response code, it throws me an exception with a URL i need.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://google.com
```

How to get this URL after I successfully catched the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URLConnection con = new URL("https://short.url").openConnection();

con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
String new_url = con.getHeaderField("Location");
con = new URL(new_url).openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
URLAfterRedirect = String.valueOf(con.getURL());
is.close();
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve method setInstanceFollowRedirects". Sorry, couldn't find suitable import (URL, URLConnection,HTTPURLConnection didnt help)

Comment: Cast con to HttpURLConnection